# Event Tracking not Appearing In Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use [Google Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) to record when a certain user action is taken. I have a JS method called `runGABanner` that fires the Google Analytics code when conditions are met, but I'm not seeing anything update in GA Admin page.

In my code, I set up the GA code as such:

```
const runGABanner = () =>{

    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: 'AdBlocker',
        eventAction: 'Ad Blocker Displayed',
        eventLabel: 'Ad Blocker'
    });
 }
```

I was expecting to see "**Banner Displayed**" under "Event Action", but as the screenshot shows, nothing is appearing there.

[image]

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: What is the code with which you send 'website-player' event?

Comment: The code is similar to the block above. That's why I was confused.